# Windows Phone get the Phone Number of an incoming call

Tags: c#-4.0, mobile, windows-phone-7, phone-call

Is it possible to get the phone number of a incoming call and record it using Windows Mobile 7.0 or later versions. I have tried OpenNETCF.IoC(1.0.12221) but i could not find a way to do it.Wasted about 2 days searching for this.If somebody can help me out it would be a great help . **Simply the app must be able to detect the phone number of the incoming call**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. There are no Windows Phone APIs for handling calls. Microsoft have supplied a deliberately restrictive set of APIs so that developers cannot interfere with the core phone functions.

Answer (score 0):

Write it for Android and run it on Windows in a couple months. That's what most of the WP developers I know plan on doing. Android "intents" handle this scenario very well.